# In my Django portal after login to the portal my request.user is always giving the value AnonymousUser

Tags: python, django, authentication

```
def login(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

               userEmail = strip_html(form.cleaned_data['auth_email'])
               userPassword = strip_html(form.cleaned_data['auth_password'])
               try:
                person = Auth.objects.get(auth_email=userEmail, auth_password=userPassword)
                request.session['username'] = person.auth_name


    return redirect("/crudapplication/show")
                except:
                    page = 'login.html'
                    message = 'Username doesn\'t exist'
```

Above is a small code snipet. This is my login functionality.So the value of the user email and password I'm providing is present in my database.

So when I'm printing the line on console by print(request.user) it always gives the value Anonymoususer. The login function is the part of views.py of my login module

Comment: This is not how you log users in. Please read the docs on authentication.

Comment: This is not how you authenticate a user in Django (use [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users)). Also after you've verified that the user is authenticated you need to actually log her in using [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login). What is `Auth` by the way? How is it possible that the password matches this way? Are you storing passwords plain-text in your database???? Maybe read [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/) from the top!

Comment: But also note it looks like you have implemented your own Auth model, which **you must not do**, especially as you appear to be storing the password in plain text. You **must** delete this code and go and read how to use Django's own - secure - auth framework.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I got your point.. So what do u suggest?? shouldn't I create my own authentication system?? or should I use django auth framework for the authentication??   Actually I'm new in Django so having these basic doubts..

Comment: There's absolutely no doubt to be had. You should use Django's auth system.

Comment: @DanielRoseman,,,Ok then I'll replace my own customize authentication system with the default django auth...thank you for suggestion and help....I was wandering since last 3 days ....

Comment: One more thing.....So when we do python manage.py migrate in my DB some default tables are being created right.. So if i want to add some extra column in my auth table so where should i do it...Bcz I'm not defining any models.py for the default in built tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing authentication in a very manual way. The problems this can cause are 2:

- Code that doesn't work
- More time invested

The objective of using django that is a framework is not to have to do the work from 0, therefore it uses the tools that django has.

For this case use the django authentication system:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/

The above is the official documentation, however to understand how authentication works on a personal level I was more helped by the following tutorial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

Comment: I followed this URL..Now I'm implementing the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
def login_user(request):
    print(request.POST)
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    print(username)
    print(password)
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("/crudapplication/show")
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Above is my views.py file and below I'm mentioning my template file.

```
<form method="post" action="/authLogin/login/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
  </form>
```

Everything works fine now..but i just wanted to know the form object that I'm using in my template file how will I pass this objevt from my views.py file?